# Solving the given differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$\dot{x_t}=a(y_t-b)$$

I would ilke to solve This differential equation.

a,b>0.

__

What I have done is

$${\partial x_t\over \partial t}= a(y_t-b)$$

$${1\over a} \partial x_t= (y_t-b) \partial t$$

$$\int {1\over a} \partial x_t= \int (y_t-b) \partial t$$

$$ {x_t\over a}+c= (1/2)y_t^2 -by_t$$

Is this true? I am not ssure since I have two variables.

Comment: Can you comment on why you think the last step is correct? What is the context of this task, what is known about $y_t$?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann I thank this is not correct. Thus I have asked it.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann I need to interpret these in economic basis. I just need to solve these equations. Here I asked mathematical part of this question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32702/what-is-economic-interpretation-of-three-nonlinear-equations

Comment: No that last step is simply wrong, $y$ is a function of $t$ and $t$, not $y$, is the integration variable. Without knowing anything else about $y$, the second last right side is as far as you can get.

Comment: Dear @Dr.LutzLehmann can you solve $\dot{w} $ and $\dot{c}$ in this question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32702/what-is-economic-interpretation-of-three-nonlinear-equations thanks in advance. I just have tried to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the system of differential equations
\begin{align}
\dot x&=a(y-b)\\
\dot y&=\left(1+\frac{d}{y^2}\right)y-c
\end{align}
you can not solve the first equation without first solving the second equation. The second equation is autonomous and separable, so that at least an implicit solution can be found
$$
t+c=\int\frac{y\,dy}{y^2-cy+d}
$$
Depending on the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial in the denominator, the right side gives terms in logarithms and trigonometric or hyperbolic inverse tangents. Using the roots of the quadratic polynomial or their non-existence on the real axis you can also perform a qualitative discussion of the solution.

With no roots $y$ is monotonically increasing towards infinity for $y>0$, which makes $x$ a convex function. With two positive roots the lower one is attracting, the higher one repelling and solutions in between the roots are bounded by them and falling. The behavior of $x$ now depends also on the position of $b$ relative to these roots. For the middle case, $x$ now is a concave function, $\ddot x=a\dot y<0$.